# What is the purpose to use className beside functionName using colon(:)

Tags: php

See the below code to understand. Please explain when i should use this mechanism in oop.

```
class A
{
}

class B
{
    public function foo(): A
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: it's the concept of inheritance.

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: It basically tells that use the parent class function foo and then overrides it whatever I'm writing in this function.

Comment: Kindly share your code with an example.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the foo() function of class B has to return an object type of Class A, otherwise, an exception will be thrown. We can define the return type of a PHP function by using the below syntax.

```
function foo(): int
{
    return 11;
}
function bar(): Baz
{
    return new Baz();
}
```

If you run your code as below-

```
<?php 

class A
{
}

class B
{
    public function foo(): A
    {
    }
}

$b = new B();
echo $b->foo();

?>
```

Output will be-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: B::foo(): Return value must be of type A, none returned in D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php:16 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php(20): B->foo() #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 16
```

This ensures strict typing in PHP. I Hope, you have understand the answer.
You can read more about why you should use strict typing here https://dzone.com/articles/strong-typing-really-needed